# Fetching Data from XML along with the Conditions in a single Query

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

```
declare @X XML=
'<Detail>
 <Gender>M</Gender>
 </Detail>'
```

I'm tring to query this above simple XML, I want to calculate the value present in Gender Tag

**if this has the value 'M' then i want to get back the result as 1**
**else if this has the value 'F' then i want to get back the result as 2**
**else return back 0**

We can easily done this by using the below query to return the Gender Value as M

```
SELECT 
@X.value('(Detail/Gender)[1]', 'varchar') as Gender
```

Then storing in a local Variable then using the Condition Statements we have to Calculate the corresponding return value.

Is there is any way to do it while fetching from the XML itself?

I mean While selecting the Gender from the @x itself we have to use the conditional Statements to return the Final Value(i.e, 1 or 2 or 3)

This will also helps to remove the Local Variable / Query Cost,Which can done in a single Fetch itself

The below will be my Required Result which have to Obtain from a Single query

```
Gender
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @X.value('(Detail/Gender)[1]', 'varchar(max)')='M' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END  as Gender
```

Or use a catalog table and join the *keys* (M, F, ? ...) to any mapping value.

### UPDATE: Catalog Table

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Detail>
 <Gender>M</Gender>
 <Gender>F</Gender>
 <Gender>oops</Gender>
 </Detail>';

DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Code VARCHAR(1),Value VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('M',1),('F',2);

SELECT m.Value
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Detail/Gender') AS A(g)
LEFT JOIN @mockup AS m ON m.Code=g.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

Comment: Yes that's works for me with the Case statement.But i couldn't get any reference for the Catalog table that you are referring here.If you wouldn't mind please refer some links how to implement such catalog table.

Comment: That was great,thanks +1 for the clarification​ from my side